# Can't get middleware Authorization to work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authorization

I'm trying to run some authorization, but I'm running into trouble on the middleware. I did write the Gate, and it is working flawlessly with the @can blade directive. I want to block the route tho, but I get:

> **"Trying to get property of non-object " error, and it shows my Gate.**

The Gate is:

```
Gate::define('canCForm', function($user, $form){
return ($user->cargo == $form->validador1);
});
```

This is written in AuthServiceProvider.

And then route is:

```
Route::get('/formulariosrecebidos/{form}', 'FormsController@editRecebido')->middleware('can:canCForm,form');
```

Any idea? I did try to change it a lot of ways, the only way I get it to work is if I make something like '`return ($user->cargo == 'somestring');`' So the problem must be in the $form. Altho it is strange because with the @can it is working.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'can:canCForm,form'` ?

Comment: Ye, my bad. I copied after testing stuff, I did try 'can:canCForm, form', still won't work.